# cmake-gui tries to open but UI not displayed

Tags: windows, cmake, compilation, cmake-gui

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall CMake using the last version in Windows. When I launch cmake-gui.exe, the process is started, seems like everything is fine but the UI is not displayed. The preview in the task bar only shows a blank screen but it's not able to display anything.

[image]

I also tried running as Administrator, same problem. Any idea? I also checked in regedit variables pointing to CMake cache files but couldn't find something relevant ...

Any idea would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

RaC

Comment: When installing CMake with the installer, it will typically over-write (uninstall) the old version of CMake for you, so there is no need to manually uninstall. This is the case, unless, of course, you want to change the installation directory or do something else atypical.

Comment: I reinstalled on a previous version as you mentioned, but this is not related to the issue. Still the UI is not coming up even if the process is running.

Comment: The window may be displayed outside of the visible screen area. Try to maximize the window from the taskbar (right mouse click on the preview image -> Maximize).

Comment: See https://discourse.cmake.org/t/unable-to-open-cmake-on-windows-10/816 for the full story.

Comment: @vre Thanks, I was trying to do it with the Windows keystroke and moving the window to the left or right as I was thinking it could be that but was not working. Didn't know that it was possible to maximize the window from the preview image. This worked. Thank you very much, good day during these COVID.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In some rare cases the cmake-gui window is displayed outside of the visible screen area. Maximizing the window from the taskbar (right mouse click on the preview image -> Maximize) should place it on the visible area again.

See [discussion](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/unable-to-open-cmake-on-windows-10/816/3) on CMake Discourse.